# API Gateway: Any random API key is able to authorise request

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have created an API endpoint using API Gateway. My Cloudformation template looks like this

```
  ServerlessApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: MyApi
      StageName: v1
      DefinitionBody:
        openapi: 3.0.1
        info:
          title: My API Endpoint
          version: v1
        paths:
          getdata:
            get:
              security:
              - api_key: []
              parameters:
              - name: X-Api-Key
                description: YOUR_API_KEY
                in: header
                required: true
                schema:
                  type: string
              x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: PipelineTriggerValidator
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                type: aws_proxy
                httpMethod: POST
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${DataLambdaFunction}/invocations
                passthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: 200
                    headers:
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
              responses:
                "200":
                  description: "Successful Response"
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        $ref: "#/definitions/Data"
        securitySchemes:
          api_key:
            type: apiKey
            name: X-Api-Key
            in: header
        definitions:
          Data:
            type: array
            items:
              type: array
              items: {}
        x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
          PipelineTriggerValidator:
            validateRequestParameters: true
            validateRequestBody: true


  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # API keys and usage plan
  # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ApiUsagePlan:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
    Properties:
      UsagePlanName: !Ref AWS::StackName
      ApiStages:
      - ApiId: !Ref ServerlessApi
        Stage: !Ref ServerlessApi.Stage

  ApiKey:
    DependsOn: ServerlessApi
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-apikey
      Enabled: true

  ApiUsagePlanKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey
    Properties:
      UsagePlanId: !Ref ApiUsagePlan
      KeyType: API_KEY
      KeyId: !Ref ApiKey
```

Now there are 2 main concerns.

1. If I use my GET endpoint without header (X-Api-Key), I get 400 (Bad Request) instead of 403 (Forbidden). You can see in the image below but from the docs practically I should get 403 (Forbidden)
   [image]
2. The 2nd major issue is that when I use `X-Api-Key` header in the request, API Gateway accepts any random string and accepts authentication.
   [image]

Also in AWS console if I go to my method request I see that API key is not enabled in the API Gateway method request. And it says API is linked to a usage plan but no API key is required. I was wondering how it is possible if I have enabled it in the resource and Postman screenshot also says that it is a required parameter.

I'm sure I am doing something wrong but out of ideas right now.
[image]